# Python Request POST not correct?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

i want to send a file with python requests to a device. According to the API it should work as follows.

```
Example 1: Single-part audio data transmit with G.711 μ-law (authorization omitted).
POST /bha-api/audio-transmit.cgi HTTP/1.0\\r\\n
Content Type: audio/basic\\r\\n
Content Length: 9999999\\r\\n
Connection: Keep Alive\\r\\n
Cache control: no-cache\\r\\n
\\r\\n
\<AUDIODATA\>
\<AUDIODATA\>
\<AUDIODATA\>
...
Example 2: Usage with gstreamer.
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc ! queue ! audioconvert ! audio resample ! "audio/x-
raw,format=S16LE,rate=8000,channels=1" ! mulawenc ! "audio/x-
mulaw,rate=8000,channels=1" ! curlhttpsink
location=http://\<device-ip\>/bha-api/audio-transmit.cgi content-
type="audio/basic" use-content-length=true user=xxxxxx0001 passwd=xxxxxxxx

Example 3: Usage with curl.
curl -v --http1.0 -H "Content-Type: audio/basic" -H "Content-Length:
9999999" -H "Connection: Keep-Alive" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" --data-
binary "@audio_file.ulaw" 'http://userxx0001:passwordxx@\<device-ip\>/bha-
api/audio-transmit.cgi' --limit-rate 8K
```

i converted the file on https://g711.org/ to a u-law wav.

my python codeversion looks like this:

```
filepath = Path(os.path.join(full_path, file))
print(filepath)

def patch_send():
  old_send = HTTPConnection.send
  def new_send(self, data):
      print(f'{"-"*9} BEGIN REQUEST {"-"*9}')
      print(data.decode('utf-8').strip())
      print(f'{"-"*10} END REQUEST {"-"*10}')
      return old_send(self, data)
      HTTPConnection.send = new_send

patch_send()

HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'
HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 0
with open(filepath, mode='r', buffering=128 ) as file:
    fileobj = file.read()

response= requests.post(url= "http://192.168.178.9/bha-api/audio-transmit.cgi",
                    headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0","Content-Type": "audio/basic; ","Connection": "keep-alive", "Cache-Control": "no-cache", "Content-Length": str(len(fileobj))},
                    auth= ('ghevxxxx', '7vfxxxxx'),
                    stream= True,
                    data = fileobj,
                    timeout=12
                )
```

This is the printed Request
--------- BEGIN REQUEST ---------
POST /bha-api/audio-transmit.cgi HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: audio/basic;
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 55844
Authorization: Basic ZxxxxxxxxxxxRo
---------- END REQUEST ----------

I always get the following error message:
`('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\r\n'))`
You can also hear something being played.
But it's not my file, just a 2s long beep.

I dont know whats not correct with the request? I use windows for coding and testing..

Comment: I'm not seeing any \r\n in that output string.

Comment: Yes, i think its the response from the server, the api said its a http1.0 connection..

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.  How are you reading the text starting with "Single-part audio data" into your code?  It seems that you are losing the \\r\\n that needs to be at the end of each line.

Comment: With open() ..  or did you mean the response? The response i couldnt print as raw data ..

Comment: Could you actually show the code where you read the text.  You are doing something that is causing the newlines to be eaten.

Comment: Could you actually show the code where you read the text.  You are doing something that is causing the newlines to be eaten.

Comment: Ok, do you think i should readlines() instead of read() ? Does an audio file includes /r/n at the end of each line?

Comment: No, but the text before the actual audio have a precise format.

Comment: Youre right, 
file.read() 
produces an other output as file.readlines() 

so i think readlines is the better option
because the output looks llika an file format 
'['RIFF\x1cÚ\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x12\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x01\x00@\x1f\x00\x00@\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00fact\x04\x00\x00\x00éÙ\x00\x00dataéÙ\x00\x00ùtpüíéxúóvtðîþðeiòïûk`eîääçòz{õîlhyü~yoa_kêÛÝíèðükd}ò{kjloam}ëàÞÜæû_gúíïe_rgwðõ{yÛÛå{n|uûoik]kóíïøôtñêïïóíe`}opjùéöàìm_fäèëôfj`~îñ~}ãàõlf^hïáwrqsyäÞîöîç{kgk[`jzý÷ïãßéßæðlyôjZm^RcûâæÙØäÞæüvlyh__[YZkòÖÑÛÕÚõûî~`^j]R_i]÷ÛØ.'

Comment: or what do you think is, how i should read the file ?
i dont know what the best option is ..